# Binary Simulation Using LEDS in C

Tags: c, loops, raspberry-pi, binary, led

The goal is to take any int negative or positive and get the binary of it. then take that binary if it is 4 digits or less and display it on LEDS on raspberry Pi. No matter what display the binary with printf. It needs to be scalable so if you want to add more leds it should be easy only having to add pin numbers to the data structure without other effort to modify the program.  this needs to be a loop so after it prints the binary it asks to find it again the wiring pi numbers I am using for my LEDs are 0,2,3,5

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>


int main()
{

int displayNumber;

wiringPiSetup();

pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(5, OUTPUT);


digitalWrite(0, LOW);
digitalWrite(2, LOW);
digitalWrite(3, LOW);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);

printf("Please select a number to display!\n");

scanf("%i", &displayNumber);


switch (displayNumber) {

case 0:
printf("0");
digitalWrite(0, LOW);
digitalWrite(2, LOW);
digitalWrite(3, LOW);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);
break;

case 1:
printf("1");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, LOW);
digitalWrite(3, LOW);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);
break;

case 2:
printf("10");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, LOW);
digitalWrite(3, LOW);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);
break;

case 3:
printf("11");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(3, LOW);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);
break;

case 4:
printf("100");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, LOW);
digitalWrite(3, LOW);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);

break;

case 5:
printf("101");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, LOW);
digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);

break;

case 6:
printf("110");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(3, LOW);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);

break;
case 7:
printf("111");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);

break;
case 8:
printf("1000");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, LOW);
digitalWrite(3, LOW);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);

break;
case 9:
printf("1001");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, LOW);
digitalWrite(3, LOW);
digitalWrite(5, HIGH);

break;
case 10:
printf("1010");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, LOW);
digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);

break;
case 11:
printf("1011");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, LOW);
digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(5, HIGH);

break;
case 12:
printf("1100");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(3, LOW);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);

break;
case 13:
printf("1101");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(3, LOW);
digitalWrite(5, HIGH);

break;
case 14:
printf("1110");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(5, LOW);

break;
case 15:
printf("1111");
digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
break;


}



return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. We can help you fix and write your own code but not do all the work for you. Please try something, show what you have tried and ask a specific question about that code.

Comment: Can you use C++?

Comment: I can only use C

Comment: Thank you for posting your code. But you have not actually asked any question. What is it you would like help with specifically? Is there some incorrect behaviour in your code? Is it crashing? Is it too slow? ...?

Comment: the goal is to do everything stated at the top my code is doing it manually typing every situation. It needs to be able to do any positive or negative int and be able to still light the leds when 4 bit binary or less is converted and looped to keep asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function as shown below to write to the pin. Note that I have used `unsigned int` for the parameters. This is to avoid undefined behaviour in bitwise operations.

```
#define NO_PINS 4
#define MAXNO 16
int pinnos[NO_PINS] = {0,2,3,5}

void writetopin (unsigned int num)
{ 
  if (num >MAXNO) {
     // handle this condition
  }
  else {
     unsigned int mask = 0x01;
     for (i=0; i<NO_PINS; i++) {
        unsigned int curr = num & mask;
        if (curr == 0) {
          digitalWrite(pinnos[i], LOW);
        }
        else {
          digitalWrite(pinnos[i], HIGH);
        }
        mask = mask << 1; 
     }
  }
}
```

This function will handle only positive integers. To handle negative you need to define the sign bit and also the no of bits used for display.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for virtually any number of available GPIO pins. It works with both signed/unsigned numbers and calculates the mask required to get the desired bits off the number and display it. It also loops and asks for the input repeatedly untill EOF (ctrl+D) is pressed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <cstdint>

/* define led pins here */
int pins[] = {2, 3 , 4, 5};

void turn_led_on(int led)
{
    digitalWrite(pins[led], HIGH);        
}

void turn_led_off(int led)
{
    digitalWrite(pins[led], LOW);
}

void display_number(int number)
{
    int num_of_leds = sizeof(pins) / sizeof(int);

    printf("The number is: %d\n", number);

    uint8_t led_mask = (1 << num_of_leds) - 1;

    int masked_number = number & led_mask;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_leds; i++) {
        if (masked_number & (1 << i)) {
            turn_led_on(i);
        } else {
            turn_led_off(i);
        }
    }
}

void initialize_leds()
{
    int num_of_leds = sizeof(pins) / sizeof(int);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_leds; i++) {
        pinMode(pins[i], OUTPUT);
        turn_led_off(pins[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int number;

    wiringPiSetup();

    initialize_leds(); 

    int ret;

    while (true) {
        printf("Please select a number to display!\n");
        ret = scanf("%i", &number);

        if (ret == EOF)
            break;

        display_number(number);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers show how to map bits to GPIO pins. A little more explanation follows here, and I address the `printf` part:

Keep in mind your integer is a binary representation in memory already:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

It is probably 4 bytes. You can use bitwise operations to test each bit in your 32-bit chain, and build a string along the way:

```
char buffer[33];
int value = -1; //for example
unsigned int mask = 1;
int i;

buffer[32] = 0; //null terminate
for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
  if (value & mask) buffer[31-i] = '1'; //test each bit position
  else buffer[31-i] = '0';
  mask = mask << 1; //shift high bit in mask one position left
}
printf("$s\n",buffer);
```

Each time through the loop, `mask` shifts its single high bit one position to the left. The `&` is the bitwise AND operator..each bit of `value` is AND-ed with the corresponding bit in `mask`, and the result is stored bit by bit. Since `mask` has only one bit high, the bitwise AND evaluates true only when `value` has a bit high in the same position. In this way you can test which bits of `value` are high, one at a time, from least significant bit to most significant bit. At the end, `buffer` will reflect just how those 32 bits are used to represent `value` in memory. Negative numbers will probably be in "two's complement" form.